# Internal Error: no cycle found in Scons Build

Tags: scons, google-developers-console

When I build my **Sconstruct file**, I am getting the below error.

```
scons: *** Found dependency cycle(s):
  build/sselser/sselConfigArgs.h -> build/sselser/sselConfigArgs.h
  Internal Error: no cycle found for node build/sselser/sselMain (<SCons.Node.FS.File instance at 0x9f61e8>) in state pending
  Internal Error: no cycle found for node build/sselser/sselMain.o (<SCons.Node.FS.File instance at 0x9f2e68>) in state pending

File "/nfs/scons/scons-1.3.0/lib/scons-1.3.0/SCons/Taskmaster.py", line 1026, in cleanup
```

I guess this is due to dependency of sselMain in sselTransorm as the error occurs during the build of sselTransform directory.

**Makefile in sselTransform:**

```
UNIT_SUPPORT_FILES += ../sselser/sselMain intest ../../../make/Makenv

MDE_SUPPORT_FILES += ../sselser/sselMain intest ../../../make/Makenv
```

I need to add the same in Sconscript of sselTransform directory to resolve this issue.

How to resolve this issue?

**Sconscript:**

```
#Set CPPPATH, RPATH, DEFINES and CCFLAGS

env = Environment(CPPPATH =['.','../sselTransform','../sselSm','../sselSRC'],
RPATH = ['/l-n/app/colr/lib/infra/SunOS5.10/WS12.0'],CPPDEFINES = ['THREADSAFE','_RWSTD_SOLARIS_THREADS','_SVID_GETTO
D','DEBUG','sun5'],CCFLAGS = ['library=rwtools7_std','features=no%tmplife','-pta','-mt','-xdebugformat=stabs','-g0','-xildoff'])

env['CXX']=CXX

Src = Split('sselManager.C PromoNotifyMgr.C ')
env.StaticLibrary('libSselser-g0.a',Src)

Src1 = Split('sselMain.C  sselManager.o PromoNotifyMgr.o ')

env.Program('sselMain',Src1)

configfile = 'sselConfigArgs.h'

CONFIG_PATH = '../../build/include/'

CONFIG=CONFIG_PATH+configfile

env.Command(CONFIG,configfile,
           [Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
           Chmod('$TARGET', 0444)])
```

**Sconstruct**:

```
SConscript('src/ssel/sselser/SConscript',variant_dir='build/sselser',duplicate=0,exports='env')
```

Comment: Just to point out - this is clearly not an answer, so left in comments - that's a really old version of SCons you're using (1.3.0 was released 2010-03-25). Current is 4.3 which lets you use Python 3, etc.

Comment: It's hard to see what's wrong when you don't include any of your SCons logic. Lists of files will be entered as Python lists so consider that a syntax pointer...

Comment: Please share a small reproducer? And try with newest SCons..

Comment: I have a scenario where I have .C file(hello.C) which includes a header in it(sample.h).   I want to copy the header file to build directory,which shows found dependency cycle for the header file. I want to copy that to include directory. But copying that to include directory also doesnt work. How to ignore the dependency of a header file in build directory?                                                                       build/sselser/sselConfigArgs.h -> build/sselser/sselConfigArgs.h

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

Notes:

1. I'm saving the build objects for your two source files and using those in both the program and static library.
2. I've added the target dir you're copying the header file to earlier in the CPPPATH.
3. You could have skipped the variables configfile, CONFIG_PATH, CONFIG and just used the strings in your Command.
4. You are using a VERY old version of SCons. If you're limited to python 2.7 please try using SCons 3.0.1? If you're not and can use Python 3.6, then try using SCons 4.3.0.

   ```
   #Set CPPPATH, RPATH, DEFINES and CCFLAGS

   env = Environment(
      CPPPATH =['.','../include','../sselTransform','../sselSm','../sselSRC'],
      RPATH = ['/l-n/app/colr/lib/infra/SunOS5.10/WS12.0'],
      CPPDEFINES = ['THREADSAFE','_RWSTD_SOLARIS_THREADS','_SVID_GETTOD','DEBUG','sun5'],
      CCFLAGS = ['library=rwtools7_std','features=no%tmplife','-pta','-mt','-xdebugformat=stabs','-g0','-xildoff'])

   env['CXX']=CXX

   Src = ['sselManager.C','PromoNotifyMgr.C']
   objects = []
   for s in Src:
       objects.extend(env.StaticObject(s))

   env.StaticLibrary('Sselser-g0',objects)

   Src1 = ['sselMain.C'] + objects

   env.Program('sselMain', Src1)

   configfile = 'sselConfigArgs.h'

   CONFIG_PATH = '../include/'

   CONFIG=CONFIG_PATH+configfile

   env.Command(CONFIG, configfile,
              [Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
              Chmod('$TARGET', 0444)])
   ```